# NavigationController.navigationBar.alpha AppDelegate Not work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem in iOS7
I want to set Opacity in navigationbar in AppDelegate not work

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

self.homeController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [UINavigationController new];

// Set alpha not work in appDelegate
navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.7f;    

self.window.rootViewController =  [navigationController initWithRootViewController:self.homeController];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are trying to assign the alpha value, navigationBar is not initialised.
Do it by below way:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.homeController];

// Set alpha not work in appDelegate
navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.7f;    

self.window.rootViewController =  navigationController;
```